# Bluecove on Mac OS 10.9

Tags: java, android, eclipse, osx-mavericks, bluecove

I am trying to connect my android device to PC using bluecove. It worked fine on Windows but gives me the following issue on MAC (OS 10.9, Mavericks):

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _IOBluetoothLocalDeviceReadSupportedFeatures
Referenced from: /private/var/folders/cq/f5chm1950m5_n2s5bk1bjfyh0000gn/T/bluecove_0/libbluecove.jnilib
Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/IOBluetooth.framework/Versions/A/IOBluetooth

dyld: Symbol not found: _IOBluetoothLocalDeviceReadSupportedFeatures
Referenced from:  /private/var/folders/cq/f5chm1950m5_n2s5bk1bjfyh0000gn/T/bluecove_0/libbluecove.jnilib
Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/IOBluetooth.framework/Versions/A/IOBluetooth
```

After researching a bit, I found out that it breaks on 10.8 and of the hacks is to run Java in 32 bit mode but 10.9 does not even allow me to run a java instance in 32 bit mode.

How can I get rid of the above error? Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Basically the error msg says you use a native library via JNI that does not have the symbol `_IOBluetoothLocalDeviceReadSupportedFeatures`. This is usually indicating that you use a different version of a library than intended by the author.

Comment: I am using bluecove-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar right now. Can you please elaborate a little bit more on how I can find out the version intended by the author?

Comment: The issue is similar to this one: https://code.google.com/p/bluecove/issues/detail?id=134

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. Just try the Bluecove example application, add it in the projects of your NetBeans folder. Then add Bluecove 2.1.2 jar to your library. Now if you run the application you can see the output as expected.

Comment: where did you find Bluecove 2.1.2 ? From http://snapshot.bluecove.org/distribution/download/ it seems last version is 2.1.1 and project has not been updated since 2010 !

Comment: There's a link to 2.1.2 here in the comments. Looks like someone built a newer version and named it 2.1.2: https://code.google.com/archive/p/bluecove/issues/134

Comment: I couldn't find it using the links above, but I found it here. https://mvn.uworks.cc/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/net/sf/bluecove/bluecove/2.1.2/

Comment: If you add ```https://mvn.uworks.cc/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/``` as a repository, you can include it in using gradle with ```implementation("net.sf.bluecove:bluecove:2.1.2")```