# How to run BlueCove (or any Bluetooth Java library) on Macbook Pro M1

Tags: java, macos, bluetooth, bluecove

I am building a JAVA desktop app that can advertise via BLE to nearby android devices.

I stumbled across [BlueCove](http://www.bluecove.org/) which seems to be Java's bluetooth API.

Whenever I try to use BlueCove in my Java application on my MacBook Pro M1, I am getting the following error:

```
Native Library bluecove not available
Exception in thread "main" javax.bluetooth.BluetoothStateException: BlueCove library bluecove not available
    at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl.loadNativeLibraries(BlueCoveImpl.java:381)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl.detectStack(BlueCoveImpl.java:434)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl.access$500(BlueCoveImpl.java:65)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl$1.run(BlueCoveImpl.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl.detectStackPrivileged(BlueCoveImpl.java:1018)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl.getBluetoothStack(BlueCoveImpl.java:1011)
    at javax.bluetooth.LocalDevice.getLocalDeviceInstance(LocalDevice.java:75)
    at javax.bluetooth.LocalDevice.getLocalDevice(LocalDevice.java:95)
```

I found online that you need to use the `-d32` parameter when launching your java application. I tried that but I get a `Unrecognized option: -d32`. [Answers like these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36300699/1315110) say that there is an unreleased version 2.1.2 which works on a Mac but [the link you](https://code.google.com/archive/p/bluecove/issues/134) can find online seems to be broken.

Was anyone able to have BlueCove (or any Java Bluetooth API) working in their Java application?